# Function infinite loop and ignoring parts of other functions

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Okay, so basically all I wrote this script to do is clear and click a button if the textbox is full and refresh the page if its not.

I can successfully clear the text box when its full and refresh the page when its not, but as soon as I try to use my clickButton function it kicks into an infinite loop and skips the if() in clrLog

```js
function addFunction(func, exec) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.textContent = '-' + func + (exec ? '()' : '');
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  document.body.removeChild(script);
}
function clickButton(val) {
  buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
  {
    if (buttons[i].type == 'submit' && buttons[i].value == val)
    {
      buttons[i].click();
    }
  }
}
function clrLog() {
  var elements = [
  ];
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName('logarea');
  if (elements.log.value === '')
  setTimeout(function () {
    location.reload();
  }, 5000);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].value = '';
  }
  clickButton('Edit log file');
}
function main() {
  addFunction(clrLog(), true);
}
main();
```

Comment: Ad infinite number of clicks, put `console.log(buttons.length)` inside the for loop in `clickButton`. It could be that clicking a button adds another button, and b`buttons` is a live collection, which can grow while your loop executes (one of quirks of some DOM methods)

Comment: Also in `main` your `addFunction(clrLog(), true);` seems to be equivalent to just doing `crlLog()`. When you do `addFunction(clrLog(), true);` you pass **the return value** of `clrLog()` call to the `addFunction`, which is `undefined`, not the function itself

Comment: I'd also add curly braces and indentation after `if` in crlLog to be more clear what should be conditionally executed. Right now only `setTimeout` is conditional, and the rest is executed always.

Comment: I done what you said, it comes back as a single number - 2

Comment: also, the curly brackets didn't help much :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that I could avoid using a for loop by using document.querySelector(); instead - so much easier :)